# Its posible decode a .p12 file with asn1js and pki.js?

Tags: pki, asn.1, xades

p12 file from where I want to extract public and private keys and the x509 certificate with pki.js But my .p12 file has a password how can I decode it. For example:

```
 const asn1js = require("asn1js");
 const pkijs = require("pkijs");
 const Certificate = pkijs.Certificate;

 let path = __dirname + "/file.p12";
 let file = fs.readFileSync(path);


 const asn1 = asn1js.fromBER(file);
 //What do I do with the password for the .p12 file?
 const certificate = new Certificate({ schema: asn1.result });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of doing this in the PKIjs repository; https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/tree/master/examples/NodePKCS12Example